# Log4net with MySql not logging

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, logging, log4net

In properties of log I noticied all the level logs (IsErrorEnabled) have value false, in log.Logger.Repository.Configured has value false.

I dont know if LogManager can't find the log4net node in app.config or there's something wrong in xml.

I'm trying:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestLog()
        {
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            log.Debug("teste");
        }
```

Before, I used Sql and all worked perfectly, but since I changed to MySql the logs dont work anymore.

Can anyone help me?

This is my XML

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data" />
      <connectionString value="Server=localserver;Database=DataBaseName;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO LogServico ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception);" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm find the errors.

Thanks [stuartd] for reply.

First I forget the `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`

After I enable the log4net debug by:

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>

<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
            name="textWriterTraceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

So Log4net logged the error:

The command text was wrong

```
"INSERT INTO LogServico ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception);"
```

The rigth way is:

```
"INSERT INTO LogServico (Date,Thread,Level,Logger,Message,Exception) VALUES (?log_date, ?thread, ?log_level, ?logger, ?message, ?exception);"
```

And change all parameter name to ?name like:

```
<parameterName value="?log_date" />
```

So my final app.config is:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data" />
      <connectionString value="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=dbname;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO LogServico (Date,Thread,Level,Logger,Message,Exception) VALUES (?log_date, ?thread, ?log_level, ?logger, ?message, ?exception);" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="?log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="?thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="?log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="?logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="?message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="?exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

My funcional method test:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void TestLog()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            log.Error("test", new Exception("test"));
        }
```

It's important remember all that is to log in mysql. In Sql the command text can use [namecolumn] and the parameter has @nameparameter

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible reasons:

1. Your log4net config file is not set to "Copy Local" on build
2. You are not initialising log4net (ie calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure` or using an assembly attribute).
3. Your config is invalid.

As you say this worked previously, then it seems probable that it is 3, and your config is invalid.

Comment: I forget XmlConfigurator.Configure, now every is true. But until not save the log and nothing errors is showing.